# Play Framework 2.3 WS SSL Disable AlgorithmChecker

Tags: web-services, ssl, playframework-2.0

I'm currently trying to use WS in Play 2.3 to interact with the Visa Direct Payments API but I am struggling as the sandbox key provided is RSA has a key size of 1024 and, from what I've read in the source code comments, is considered not safe so is disabled.

As this is just sandbox I would like to know if there is a way to disable this extra key checking, I have already tried `ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true` without any luck.

The errors I am recieving in the console are as follows:

`[warn] p.a.l.w.s.ConfigSSLContextBuilder - validateKeyStore: Skipping certificate with weak key size in visasandboxcert: Certificate failed: cert = "CN=841edac8-d8cd-4593-b575-fdf3bbee5e67,OU=VMT,O=Visa,L=Foster City,ST=CA,C=US" failed on constraint RSA keySize < 2048, algorithm = RSA, keySize = 1024
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`

Can anyone give me any advice how I can get round this? Preferably without changing the Play source code and building from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to talk to Visa Direct Payments and file a bug report letting them know that a 1024 bit key is utterly unacceptable in this day and age.

Second, you need to set:

```
ws.ssl.disabledKeyAlgorithms="RSA keySize < 1024"
```

which will tell the Algorithms checker to ease up.  See [Certificate Validation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/CertificateValidation) for more details.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for getting back to me, adding the option let me get a step further but now I'm stuck with this error: `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` Do you know what I can check? Is it a permissions issue on the keystore?

Comment: That means the trust store you specified was not found or did not contain any "trust anchors" (which are plain old X.509 certificates inside a trust store).

Comment: I would check to see that you have your certificates set up correctly -- look at keystore explorer or one of the other certificate management tools described in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/CertificateGeneration and turn on debugging using https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/DebuggingSSL

Comment: Thanks for that. I have set up a trust store and now am back to getting a `Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` error. This is just using the trustStore in the trustManager. Do I also need to set a keystore in the keyManager of application.conf?

Comment: You only need a keystore if you are using client authentication, where the server is verifying the client is presenting a certificate signed by a CA the server trusts.  You should scroll up before the handshake failure and see where you're getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using play 2.6.x, you can do it this way

```
play.ws {
   ssl {
    debug.handshake = true
    disabledKeyAlgorithms =["RSA keySize < 1024"]
 }
}
```